# Tightness of rejection sampling

Tags: self-study, simulation, random-generation, accept-reject

[image]

Hello. I'm studying the Monte Carlo Statistical Method textbook by Robert and Casella. I have a question about exercise problem 30 in Chapter 2. I've already solved parts (a)-(c), but I'm having difficulty understanding part (d). According to part (a), a smaller M leads to a larger acceptance rate, so isn't that desirable? Despite a low acceptance rate in part (d), could there be a better situation? I would like to gain some intuition about the problem.

Comment: Yes, all other things being equal smaller M would be better. Now, the challenge is to think about what might make it worthwhile *not* to have the smallest possible M. In short, all other considerations are not always equal.

Comment: @Glen_b Could you provide any hint?

Comment: The [book](http://amzn.to/2lQDmJR) is by CaSella (and myself).

Comment: The lower acceptance rate can be compensated by a lower computational cost (per simulation or overall).

Comment: @Xi'an Thank you for great comments. I don't think the constant M has a significant impact on the computational complexity. Instead, it seems that the computations about f and g are the main contributors to the complexity. (Here, I assumed different constants M and M' for fixed f and g) Please share your opinions.

Comment: Computational complexity is not the same as runtime, although it is related.  Best not to mix the terms up :)

Comment: Certainly $M$ has a significant impact on the runtime!  Consider the trivial case of $f = g$, and set $M = 100$.  Now you have 100x the runtime you would if you set $M=1$.

Comment: @jbowman I understand what you are saying. But, isn't it still better when M is lower? I still don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: @Xi'an Thanks! I will.

Comment: I would NOT spend too much time on that question! Our point was that a larger constant  could be used for a moderate number of simulations (like =1) if computing a more accurate constant ′ proves too costly. See [this 2018 paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.09390.pdf) in that regard.